# Why am I banned from asking questions on linguistics?

Tags: support, question-ban

So I asked the following question yesterday:
[Why is anekdota written with a "k" in Czech but a "g" in Polish (anegdota)?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/47991/why-is-anekdota-written-with-a-k-in-czech-but-a-g-in-polish-anegdota)
I give a full background info and described everything. It was the first question I asked after my ban which lasted 6 months on asking on "Linguistics". I had given lots of details and yet when I tried to ask today, it didn't allow me to. Why is that?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions The mods can't do anything about this, it is an  automatic restriction.